# Same tabulation/spacing in \cvitem ModernCV

Tags: spacing, moderncv, brackets

I would be greatful for the idea how to integrate several cvitems so that the all entries would start from the same line. With the following MWE the text in the second curly braces of \cvitem starts right after the colon. The solution would be to force all second parts of items to start on the same hight.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[grey]{banking}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\firstname{Name}
\familyname{Surname}
\title{ Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Streetv 1}{City 1}{State 1}
\mobile{0 700 880}
\email{namesurename@gmail.com}

\begin{document}

\section{Skills}

\cvitem{Office software}{MS Office}
\cvitem{Programming}{R}
\cvitem{Databases}{SQL}
\cvline{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can define an own command `\mycvitem` to get the layout you want or just use the command used in file `moderncvbodyi.sty`. I only changed `\raggedleft` to `\raggedright`:

```
\newcommand*{\mycvitem}[3][.25em]{% <===================================
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedright\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}% <=================================
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}} % <===============================================
```

With the following MWE (see `<=======` for my changings)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[grey]{banking} % banking classic
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand*{\mycvitem}[3][.25em]{% <===================================
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedright\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}} % <===============================================


\firstname{Name}
\familyname{Surname}
\title{ Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Streetv 1}{City 1}{State 1}
\mobile{0 700 880}
\email{namesurename@gmail.com}

\begin{document}

\section{Skills}

\cvitem{Office software}{MS Office}
\cvitem{Programming}{R}
\cvitem{Databases}{SQL}
\mycvitem{Office software}{MS Office}
\mycvitem{Programming}{R}
\mycvitem{Databases}{SQL}
\cvline{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: resulting pdf]